# How to pass HashSet to server to test API from postman?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, java

I created an API which I want to test using postman. My api is accepting many parameters and one parameter is HAshSet. I dont know how to pass HashSet parameter using postman. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
@PutMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "collectMultiInvoices", nickname = "collectMultiInvoices")
    public BaseResponse collectAmountMultipleInvoices(@RequestParam(value = "invoice_id") HashSet<Integer> invoiceIds,
                                      @RequestParam("date") String _date,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "cash", required = false) Float cashAmount,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "chequeAmount", required = false) Float chequeAmount,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "chequeNumber", required = false) String chequeNumber,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "chequeDate", required = false) String _chequeDate,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "chequeImage", required = false) MultipartFile chequeImage,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "chequeBankName", required = false) String chequeBankName,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "chequeBankBranch", required = false) String chequeBankBranch,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "otherPaymentAmount", required = false) Float otherPaymentAmount,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "otherPaymentType", required = false) Integer otherPaymentType,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "otherPaymentTransactionId", required = false) String otherPaymentTransactionId,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "discountPercentorAmount", required = false) String discountPercentorAmount,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "discountId", required = false) String discountId) throws AppException.RequestFieldError, AppException.CollectionAmountMoreThanOutstanding {


//method implementation

}
```

Comment: Comma-separate them. `invoice_id=id1,id2,id3`

Comment: since its a PUT request, you can put all these RequestParams in json Payload Object and map with a custom class in your server side, e.g in `{"InvoiceIds":[1,2,3], "date":"29-04-2019", "cash": 502.48 ...}` and on your service side like `@PutMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "collectMultiInvoices", nickname = "collectMultiInvoices")
    public BaseResponse collectAmountMultipleInvoices(@RequestBody MultipleInvoice multipleInvoice}` where `MultipleInvoice { private Set<Integer> InvoiceIds; private String InvoiceDate, private Float cash; // setter getters ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set` or `HashSet` is a java concept.  There is no such thing as a `Set` from the HTTP perspective, and there is no such thing as a `Set` in Postman.  So from Postman, you need to send the `invoice_ids` in a format that Spring's parsing library can convert to a `HashSet`.  As @Michael pointed out in the comments, one way to do this is to comma separate the `invoice_id`s like this: `invoice_id=id1,id2,id3`.  When Spring processes this request, it will see that you are expecting data in the form of a `HashSet`, so it will attempt to convert `id1,id2,id3` into a `HashSet<Integer>`, which it knows how to do automatically.

Side note: Unless you specifically need a `HashSet`, it is considered good practice to declare your type using the interface instead of an implementing subclass.  So in this situation I would recommend changing your method signature to accept a `Set<Integer>` instead of a `HashSet<Integer>`